# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'summary'

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am running linear regression and I get the attributeError for 'summary'.

I am working on windows OS, python 3.7

```
y=dataset
X=dataset [['A'] + ['B'] + ['C'] + ['D'] + ['E']]
X1 = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(endog = y, exog = X)
results = model.fit
results.summary()
```

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'summary'

Comment: Try `results = model.fit()`

Comment: up-to model.fit() is fine; but to display the results?

Comment: What do you get by running `print(results.summary())`?

Comment: Moreover, why do you use `X1 = sm.add_constant(X)` and then use `X` in `sm.OLS`?

Comment: running print(results.summary()) yields same result unfortunately;  AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'summary'

Comment: Please, run the code I posted as answer and let me know what error (if any) you get.

Comment: How do you add the 'Constant' part in the model ?

Comment: print(results.summary()) yields AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'summary'

Comment: **Please**, run the code I posted as answer and let me know what error (if any) you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `statsmodels` [OLS example](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html):

```
import numpy as np

import statsmodels.api as sm

# Artificial data:
nsample = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
X = np.column_stack((x, x**2))
beta = np.array([1, 0.1, 10])
e = np.random.normal(size=nsample)

# Our model needs an intercept so we add a column of 1s:
X = sm.add_constant(X)
y = np.dot(X, beta) + e

# Fit and summary:
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit()

print(results.summary())

print('Parameters: ', results.params)
print('R2: ', results.rsquared)
```

In your case, `results = model.fit` has to be `results = model.fit()`.